# How to get process load avg without tools

Tags: kernel, process, load

I want to list processes and their info in my program. The most information I can get from /proc/[pid]. How does top, htop etc get the average load of a process?

Comment: Conceptually, there isn't a thing like the load of a process, as it is defined by an amount of processes on a system. Do you mean CPU time instead?

Comment: I mean the percentual amount of load the system monitors display

Answer (score 3):

The *load* of a system, is the average number of processes (thread) in the run queue (that is, running or waiting to be run) (and on Linux [processes in uninterruptible sleep](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html), the `D` state below) during some period.

On Linux, that's available in `/proc/loadavg` for the last 1, 5 and 15 minutes.

To see what those threads currently (at least at the time `ps` reads the respective `/proc/pid/task/tid/stat` files) are, you can do:

```
ps -eLo state,tid,args | awk '$1 ~ [RD]'
```

Or:

```
grep -ho '.*) [RD]' /proc/[1-9]*/task/*/stat
```

(as an approximation, assuming process names don't contain newline or `)` characters. To be correct, for the third field and over, you need to start at the last occurrence of `)` in the file).

The *load of a process* doesn't really make sense, what you're probably thinking of is the time spent by CPUs to run the process over a period.

For instance, with `top` printing a page every 1.5 seconds, when %CPU for a process shows 300%, that means that over those 1.5 seconds since the last page was printed, CPUs have been running tasks/threads of that process for a total of 4.5 seconds.

To get that information, get the sum of the `utime` (14) and `stime` (15) fields of `/proc/pid/stat` (see `man 5 proc` for details) at the start and end of the period, and get the ratio of the difference to the duration.

For instance, with `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/zselect
period=100 # centi-seconds
((clk_tck = $(getconf CLK_TCK)))
for i (1 2) {
  read -rd '' stat < /proc/$pid/stat;
  t[i]=$((${(j:+:)${(s: :)stat##*\)}[12,13]}))
  ((i == 2)) || zselect -t $period
}
printf '%.4g%%\n' $(((t[2] - t[1]) * 100. * 100 / period / clk_tck))
```

If by *process load*, you meant the average number of threads of that process in the run queue (as per the definition suggested by @Patrick in comments), you could get an approximation by getting a few samples like:

```
$ (repeat 100 grep -l ') [RD]' /proc/$pid/task/*/stat)|awk 'END{print NR/100}'
16.57
```

Over the time it took to run those 100 commands, 16.57 threads of `$pid` on average were seen in the run queue.

Comment: I would argue that the load of a process does make sense. In the typical "load average" definition, it's the number of processes waiting on run time. You could track this on a per-process basis as a process can have multiple threads, and each waiting thread contributes to the load average. So instead of calculating load using the number of processes waiting across the entire system, you'd calculate it using just the (light-weight) processes (aka threads) of that one process.

Comment: @Patrick, I see what you mean. But then, given that the system doesn't give us any statistic on how much time any thread of a process has been in the run queue, that's not something we can compute (other than by sampling which would be very inaccurate), and that's not something _the system monitors_ (to quote the OP) give.

Answer (score 1):

For the system wide load average (and some other stats), check `proc/loadavg`.  The first three fields are the load average for 1, 5, and 15 minutes, which is what most system monitors display.  The fourth field consists of two numbers separated by a slash, the first is the number of runnable processes, the second is the total number of processes (including threads).  The fifth field is the PID of the newest process on the system.

If you want more detalied stats, you'll have to either talk to the kernel over netlink (not particularly easy), or scan the numbered directories in `/proc` (not reliable because of TOCTOU races).  The relevant file for what you want is probably `/proc/<PID>/stat`, which contains a majority of the other information shown by most task managers.  The exact explanation is a bit long to post here, but it's covered pretty well in the manpage for the proc filesystem (`man proc` in a terminal).

It's worth noting by the way that 'load' does not make sense in the context of a process.  The load average is the average number of processes that are in the runnable state over a given period of time (which is a really crappy measure of how busy the system is, but that's another story), so by definition a given process can't have a 'load' value.  Processes generate load on the system, but they do not have 'load' themselves.  The closest thing to this is the amount of CPU time the process uses, which is pretty easy to compute by pollinb the above mentioned file (The answer from Stéphane Chazelas covers how to compute this pretty well, so I won't repeat it here).

Comment: TOCTOU is okay, but where do I get the per process load?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a bit more clarification.